# imcrop with area defined by impoly?

Tags: image, matlab, crop

I use the following code to crop an image according to a rectangular selection generated with `imrect()`:

```
figure();
imshow(img);
h = imrect();
crop_area = wait(h);
cropped = imcrop(img, crop_area);
```

But naturally, the region of interest might not be rectangular, or might be tilted, etc.

Therefore my question: is there a way to use `impoly()` with `imcrop()`?

Comment: @tedteng do you have a code example? I'm using `roipoly()` for now.

Comment: you found yourself a solution! I can't believe I forgot about roipoly()...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems like `roipoly()` is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Using `impoly()` with `imcrop()` does not make sense, since a digital image always has to be rectangular.

You can use `impoly()` together with `createMask()` if you wish to select and manipulate non-rectangular ROIs.